# Aspx gets redirected to itself (exactly the same url) - firstly status 302 then status 200

Tags: asp.net, redirect, iis, webforms

I am working on web project (Web forms) and I am having strange problem: when I refresh my page, its Page_Load event is fired and status 302 is returned. Redirect goes to exactly the same url, Page_Load is fired again and status 200 is returned.

Few facts:

- `AutoEventWireup` property is set to false
- property `MasterPageFile` is set
- I haven't found any `<img src="">` or `<img src="#">` on the page
- redirect is not always happening (lets say it happens on 80% of requests for the same aspx)

How to prevent this behaviour and how to achive only one page load per request? What would be the purpuse of redirection to exactly the same url?

Tnx in advance!

**EDIT 2018-05-23 16:15:** I am attaching print screen from google dev tools:
[Google dev tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePVRK.png)

**EDIT 2017-05-29 09:13:** Ok, obviously this is expected behaviour. [This answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/74509) refers to curl, but I think it also answers my question. Those redirect are intermittent and caused by IIS. My next question is: how to detect this kind of redirects and prevent duplicate code run. In my case I am doing some access logging and in case of redirect access to specific page is logged twice...

Comment: Anything special in that Page_Load? And it is after a refresh, not a Post/Redirect/Get situation?

Comment: Nothing special - showing/hiding controls,... Usual stuff. Did you have anything specific in mind? The problem is that I am doing some logging on page opening and because of that redirect stuff gets logged twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution. I should've mentioned that application is "hosted" on SharePoint. I believe that problem is that IIS only serves but doesn't know anything about specific page. Everytime when cache expires or when recycle happens, IIS asks SP for content and when content is returned, IIS firstly responds with status "302 Found" and then with status "200".

My solution was to check response status and leave event if response status equals status "302 found" (VB.NET code):

```
If Response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Found Then Return
```